# do the followed destruct happened base on exception unwinding?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

```
Class Object {
public:
    Object() {
        this->objectMember=ObjectMember(10); 
        this->pobjectMember=new ObjectMember(20);
        throw 1;
    }

    ~Object():objectMember(10) {
        this->pobjectMember=new ObjectMember(20);
        throw 1;
    }

private:
    ObjectMember objectMember ;
    ObjectMember *pobjectMember ;
}
```

when call `Object *o = new Object()`, it will throw exception.

Q1： the member : objectMember will be destructed. So is it caused by exception unwinding or other mechanism?

Q2:  is the member pobjectMember will be destructed too? Someone mention the  pobjectMember will be deconstructed but without anything be done for pointer's destruct process? is it right?

Q3:  do the memory allocated for new Object will be freed by calling delete auto?

Any official articles discuss this issues?

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: Yes in the literal sense, but you probably asked the wrong question.

Comment: This is totally bogus code. C++ is case sensitive, you forgot the semicolon, and the constructor syntax is unnecessarily noisy. For example, a sane way to write the constructor would be: `Object() : objectMember(10), pobjectMember(new ObjectMember(20)) { throw 1; }`

Comment: Q2: The pointer `pobjectMember` will be destroyed but the object it points to will not.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1： the member : objectMember will be destructed. So is it caused by exception unwinding or other mechanism?

As of §15.2/3:

> The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to the point where an exception is thrown is called “stack unwinding.” If a destructor called during stack unwinding exits with an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1). [ Note: So destructors should generally catch exceptions and not let them propagate out of the destructor.

So, yes, that's how it's called.

---

> Q2: Is the member pobjectMember will be destructed too? Someone mention the pobjectMember will be deconstructed but without anything be done for pointer's destruct process? is it right?

From § 15.2/1:

> As control passes from the point where an exception is thrown to a handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects constructed since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.

This means that in the constructor of `Object`, when you throw the exception, both `objectMember` and `pobjectMember` will be deallocated, **but** the dynamically allocated resource of `pobjectMember` will not be freed (this is also the reason why [people recommend to use smart pointers](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)).

---

> Q3: do the memory allocated for new Object will be freed by calling delete auto?

I don't know what you mean by calling `delete auto`, but the easiest way to assure no memory leaks happens is by using smart pointers:

```
class Object {
public:

    Object()
        : objectMember(10)
        , pobjectMember(new ObjectMember(20))
        { throw 1; }

    ~Object():objectMember(10) {
        pobjectMember.reset(new ObjectMember(20));
        throw 1;
    }

private:
    ObjectMember objectMember;
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectMember> pobjectMember;
};
```

Comment: Q3: do the memory allocated for new Object will be freed by calling delete auto?

Comment: @jiafu, what's `delete auto`?

Comment: call delete operator by system?

Comment: @jiafu: Please speak in complete sentences. That doesn't make sense, there's no such thing.

Comment: in other words, if the memory allocated for new Object() will be free ed after exception popped.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1： the member : objectMember will be destructed. So is it caused by exception unwinding or other mechanism?

Stack unwinding refers to the destruction of automatic (local) variables as control passes outward and outward until a `catch` block is found that can handle the exception. The destruction of `objectmember` and `pobjectmember` in this example are not part of stack unwinding. There is also a rule that if an exception propagates out of a constructor or destructor, then all fully constructed "subobjects" (which includes both members and base classes) are destroyed. This is what's happening here. `objectmember` and `pobjectmember` are initialized before the body of the constructor are entered, so they must be destroyed when the exception is thrown.

> Q2: is the member pobjectMember will be destructed too? Someone mention the pobjectMember will be deconstructed but without anything be done for pointer's destruct process? is it right?

I think what they meant to say (and they'd be right) is that, yes, `pobjectmember` is destroyed too, but the destruction of a pointer object does not `delete` the pointer, so a memory leak occurs.

Note that `Object`'s destructor never gets called. If an object's constructor exits *via* an exception, then the object is never really created, so it doesn't get destroyed, either.

Comment: 15.2 seems to attribute the colloquialism "stack unwinding" the the entire procedure.

Comment: @KerrekSB paragraph 3 explicitly says "calling destructors for automatic objects", which is why I do not interpret the definition in that way.

Comment: @KerrekSB all of it is under assumption that there is somewhere a 'try' and 'catch' that handles this exception, right? OP didn't mention that call to Object *o = new Object(); is in try block

Comment: Check out 15.5.1/2 for that - an interesting detail.

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you. For those of you interested: 15.5.1/2: In the situation where no matching handler is found, it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before std::terminate() is called.

Comment: I want know if they are same rules for this case and stack unwinding, the I can't catch the exception, are the destructor be called for any auto members?

Comment: @jiafu if the exception is not caught, automatic variables might or might not be destroyed before the program terminates; don't assume anything. Based on the wording of 15.2 I *believe* that subobjects are destroyed even if the exception is not caught, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score -1):

> Q1： the member `objectMember` will be destructed. So is it caused by exception unwinding

Yes.

> or other mechanism?

No.

> Q2: is the member pobjectMember will be destructed too?

No.

> Someone mention the pobjectMember will be deconstructed but without anything be done for pointer's destruct process?

No. 'Someone' was wrong, or very confused. The space for `pobjectMember` will be released along with the rest of the containing object. It is not correct to refer to that as 'deconstruction'. Nothing specific happens to the object pointed to by `pobjectMember` unless you code it.

> is it right?

No.

I'm wondering why on earth you're writing code like that in the first place. Everything is wrong with it, and the destructor in particular is complete nonsense. It should be like this:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object()
    : objectMember(10),
      pobjectMember(new ObjectMember(20)) {
        throw 1;
    }

    ~Object() {
        delete pobjectMember;
        throw 1;
    }

private:
    ObjectMember objectMember ;
    ObjectMember *pobjectMember ;
}
```

Throwing an exception from a destructor is poor practice. In this case it is in fact illegal as the constructor is already throwing an exception, so you get an illegal throw-within-throw.

Comment: Q3: do the memory allocated for new Object will be freed by calling delete auto?

Comment: Q2: `pobjectMember` is destroyed (though trivially). You are confusing it with `*pobjectMember`, which is not destroyed.

Comment: "It should be like this" still has syntax error :-S

Comment: "It should be like this" -- No, it shouldn't. Still leaking.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's what I said. It is released but not destructed. I *specifically distinguished* it from what you claim I confused it with.

Comment: @EJP: Fair enough, and I noticed that, but I still find it a bit misleading. The general rule is that class object members are destroyed, and that covers all types, even if the types are trivially destructible. Making exceptions for certain types just complicates the picture unnecessarily...